# Viewing configuration values in Bazel

Tags: bazel

When debugging Bazel BUILD files, it can be useful to know what values the system has on by default or has determined from the host/target setup (eg. debugging `select` rules).

Is there a way, either through a query or directly in the BUILD file, to view platform and other configuration values (eg. cpu, os, etc)?

Is it also possible to produce a list of all of these variables? With many different configuration options available, it's easy to lose track of what's there and what they may be set to(eg. crosstool_top, host_crosstool_top, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect answer, but adding the `--toolchain_resolution_debug` flag to the command line gives some visibility into a couple of these values.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--toolchain_resolution_debug